# C# selenium chromedriver - no see update on webpage

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I use Selenium for a study project, to scroll Amazon Webpage and save items in result, price, ...

My code works, I can get all items link in the page, and then get data about its.
But my issue is that when I refresh the page, I could not see new items which appears in result (visible for any other browser). Selenium can't see it until I go to Chromedriver. When I goes to ChromeDriver (so when it become active windows?) and scroll down on the webpage, then Selenium could see the new item in the list send by Amazon.

To try to avoid this, I change between several page of Amazon, but when I comeback to the wanted page, new items are not visible.
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
I also try refresh and scroll down without success.
    driver.Navigate().Refresh();
    driver.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.PageDown);

I'm not sure if it's because the chromedriver is not the active windows (but if I have to set it as active windows I can't have several windows in the same time, and can't work on my computer at the same time). If I stop ChromeDriver and restart it, he saw new items in the result. Do you think it's link to javascript use by Amazon?

Thanks for your help / ideas.

Comment: I have really no clue what so ever what your question is. I think you must elaborate / explain more thoroughly  ...

Comment: Why do you need to _refresh the page_ at several occasions?

Comment: To see list of items, and can found new ones (to get data of these new items). But even if there is a new one (visible by any other computer / browser), ChromeDriver is always display (and check) the old list, until I go on it.